# Display the value of a session in a html page

Tags: html, session

I am trying to display the value of a session in a html tag?

The best search i could find on google to do this returned the following:

```
<p><%= Session("fileName").ToString()%></p>
```

I would like a message yo display on my web page saying, File name is "bla bla".

```
<p>File name is = Session["fileName"].tosring()</p>
```

If it was MVC i could use something similar to

```
@Html.Raw(Session["fileName"].ToString())
```

But does anyone know how to do this for a standard html webpage, i think this should be a pretty simple solution but have found nothing to show me how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: That was my attempt in displaying my session but it just displayed <%= Session("fileName").ToString()%>

Comment: Then `<%` is the wrong syntax for your (still unspecified) template language.

Comment: HTML has no concept of sessions, and `<%` has no special meaning in HTML.

Comment: Thanks i did not recognize <% as anything i have seen it html before, but that what came out with the Google searches

Comment: The "<%=" and "@Html.Raw" syntax probably come from ASP.NET pages. As others have explained, html does not know about server side syntax like that but you could try and look into php, asp.net or similar server side frameworks to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If this is Razor (with MVC) you can use

```
<p>@Html.Raw(Session["fileName"].ToString())</p>
```

If it is just a `.html` page then you are unable to do this as a session is a server side variable so you will need a server side language to retrieve it

Comment: Yup its MVC, Thanks. How would i display that in a paragraph <p></p> ?

Comment: Have edited answer to show

Comment: The i tried this it just show's the text "@Html.Raw(Session["fileName"].ToString())"

Comment: What does your Razor file look like, it is a .cshtml file you are putting this into?

Comment: Oops i don't this view i'm working on is razor think its just an HTML view, know any methods to display a session for a html view?

Comment: no, you will need some sort of programming language to add session variables into the html page.  If you are using MVC you should be able to create Razor or Asp.net pages